# Communication between two programs using file

Tags: file-io, pascal

I want two separate programs written in Pascal communicate between themselves using additional text file. It works fine for the first 2-3 messages but then it gives run-time error in either sender.pas or receiver.pas Do you know where my mistake is or do you have any suggestion?

First program receiver.pas

```
var
 f : text;
 s : string;
begin
 {I-}
 Assign(f,'main.in');
 while true do
  begin

   reset(f);
   while IOResult<>0 do      //
    begin                    // Wait until the file
     close(f);               //       is closed by sender
     reset(f);               //
    end;                     //

   if eof(f) then
    close(f)
   else
    begin
     readln(f,s);
     close(f);
     rewrite(f);
     close(f);
     writeln(s);
    end;
  end;
 {I+}
end.
```

second program sender.pas

```
var
 f : text;
 s : string;
begin
 {I-}
 Assign(f,'main.in');
 while true do
  begin
   readln(s);

   rewrite(f);                //
   while IOResult<>0 do       //
    begin                     // Wait until the file
     close(f);                //        is closed by receiver
     rewrite(f);              //
    end;                      //

   writeln(f,s);
   close(f);
  end;
 {I+}
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I noticed:

1. If rewrite fails, afaik the file was not opened and you don't have to close it? Closing an unopened file might cause runtime errors (though I assume assign will init it safely)
2. depending on how you use these, there might be in the logic. Namely that after closing a file is directly ready for opening by other apps. In general closed filehandles linger several 100ms till several seconds (depending on filesystem busines). This can cause starvation problems in such schemes. (while it would work in plain dos, which didn't linger, at least not that much)
3. The reader will crash if the file doesn't exist.
4. I assume that the {I-}/{I+} is a typo and that your sourcecode really reads {$I-} and {$I+} (note the dollar?)
5. In Windows pascal versions, read only access is not always locking. Put filemode:=2 as first line in everything.

What compiler is this? Delphi, Free Pascal? Which version?

My new (Free Pascal) receiver code becomes:

```
uses sysutils;
var
 f : text;
 s : string;
begin
 filemode := 2; // read-only
 {$I-}
 Assign(f,'main.in');
 while true do
  begin
   reset(f);
   while IOResult<>0 do      //
    begin                    // Wait until the file
     close(f);               //       is closed by sender
     sleep(1000);
     reset(f);
    end;
   if eof(f) then
    begin
      close(f);
      sleep(1000);
    end
   else
    begin
     readln(f,s);
     close(f);
     rewrite(f);
     close(f);
     writeln(s);
    end;
  end;
 {$I+}
end.
```

The new sender code is:

```
uses sysutils;
var
 f : text;
 s : string;
begin
 filemode := 2; // read-only
 {$I-}
 Assign(f,'main.in');
 while true do
  begin
   reset(f);
   while IOResult<>0 do      //
    begin                    // Wait until the file
     close(f);               //       is closed by sender
     sleep(1000);
     reset(f);
    end;
   if eof(f) then
    begin
      close(f);
      sleep(1000);
    end
   else
    begin
     readln(f,s);
     close(f);
     rewrite(f);
     close(f);
     writeln(s);
    end;
  end;
 {$I+}
end.
```

Comment: Ouch! What a stupid mistake I have done. I mean dollar signs. :D
+1 for `filemode:=2`
[EDIT] It is Free Pascal 2.2.4

Comment: The above was FPC/trunk (2.5.1). I actually looked over those directives for about 10 minutes too.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: Make sure you check IOResult after every file operation, not just rewrite/reset - don't call close if your reset/rewrite failed - and you probably want something like a Sleep(250) in those retry loops.

Comment: Why do I have to check IOResult after every operation. If I succeed opening the file, then every operation will be successful until I close the file again. Am I wrong?

Comment: I theory you have to check every I/O operation. E.g. the writeln might not be able to write because the disc is full. It can be wise to do this at least for debugging purposes now.

Comment: For example, if you had checked IOResult after Close you would have seen that it failed.